# Cloudserver Azure CDN not caching bundles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have configured my cloud service and Azure CDN based on the below article, but my bundles are not getting cached in client site. Every time its loading from server. I have also set Querystring Caching behaviour as Cache every unique url

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cdn-cloud-service-with-cdn/

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Cache-Control:no-cache

Content-Length:6350

Content-Type:text/css; charset=utf-8

Date:Wed, 27 Jan 2016 09:05:57 GMT

Expires:-1

Pragma:no-cache

Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5

X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319

X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: i generated bundle version link as v=1.2.0.1 since v is the query thing internally mvc bundle is using its clearing from caching everytime. Once i changed query string to version then it works

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the Cache-Control: no-cache header is preventing your files from being cached on the CDN. You can verify this by checking if this same header is being returned when you directly access the file from the origin.